# Adapting onto a Price-Pfister bathroom sink faucet with hidden Aerator

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

After weeks of research I've been unable to figure out what the thread size of a Pfister hidden aerator is.  I want to remove the aerator and screw on an "instant-off" aerator device.

The Pfister aerator thread size is wildly non-standard. The outside diameter of a removed aerator measures as .73", or 18.62mm.
[image]

So naturally, I figured the threads were 3/4" 27F, and I needed a 3/4" 27M adaptor to screw into it:

[image: Danco 3/4"-27M adaptor]

But that didn't work.  It's close, but it doesn't thread.

It seems as if the internal "hidden" threads inside the Pfister faucet MIGHT be MALE threads, with the threads on the removable aerator actually FEMALE 3/4" 27F.  If that's the case, it's virtually impossible to screw an adaptor in, because it doesn't seem that any adaptor would be made with female threads on the outside.

Anyone ever run into this?  Or have an idea what the actual thread size is supposed to be?

**UPDATE:**  According to Price-Pfister, the threading of the inside of the faucet is **3/4"-18F**, so an aerator or aerator adaptor would need to have MALE threads of **3/4"-18M**.  The problem is, 18M seems coarser than 27M, and if anything, the threads seem finer.  In any case, I don't think there's such a thing as an 18M-to-anything-adaptor?

The model number of the faucet is: Pfister Weller LG49-WRO

[image: View of Faucet from below]

Comment: Do you have a model number for the faucet?

Comment: Would you give us pictures of the unscrewed areator, and of the faucet w/o areator?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - it is "Pfister Weller LG49-WRO".  But see original question for more detailed information. (Pfister says the internal threads are 3/4"-18F -- seems impossible)

Comment: @DanielGriscom -- see revised original question, with pictures, and assertion from Pfister that internal threads are 3/4"-18F

Comment: Yowza! Great documentation: let's see if you get a good answer.

Comment: Are you certain that the outer portion doesn't come out? It appears to be designed to remove, judging by the crenellations. Perhaps the more standard 15/16-27 female will be there once it's removed (I know, from the picture it appears that you have already tried)...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- The outer portion DOES come off.  However, that gray outer portion is directly connected to a tube that runs down the entire faucet and connects to the mixed hot & cold water.  In other words: water doesn't run inside the metal of the fixture.  You CANNOT remove the gray fitting and expect the fixture to function.

Answer (score 1):

3/4"-18 is UNS thread (Unified Special) which is a non-typical thread size.  I am in the same situation trying to adapt a Pfister bathroom faucet to accept a swivel aerator.  Still searching.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I finally gave up, and bought a completely different brand of fixture for that bathroom!

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that a 3/4-27 is not the correct size thread for a Pfister faucet aerator.  It is some close variation to it.  I was told by a master plumber that Pfister uses their own special threading and no one makes adapters with their threads.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information 3/4-18 is “English” or sae  pipe is measured by inside diameter  the number of threads is 18 threads per inch this is a “fine” pitched adapter as normal threads are 14tpi . It is not metric so you need a 3/4-18 adapter some will just say 3/4 fine.